# Toggle button value change

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here the code which i have used to show the toggle button in my sencha based application.

```
{
   xtype: 'togglefield',
   name: 'awesome',
   value: 1,
   label: 'Enable on startup?',
   labelWidth: '60%',
   value: false,
              listeners: {
                change: function(slider, thumb, newValue, oldValue) {
               if (this.isDisabled() == false)
               {   
                   App.gvars.enablestatus='N';
               }
               else 
               {
                  this.enable();
                  App.gvars.enablestatus='Y';
               }
              }
            }
  }
```

How to change the status/value of the above toggle field from other method.Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'togglefield',
    name: 'awesome',
    label: 'Are you awesome?',
    labelWidth: '40%',
    id: 'myToggle' 
});

Ext.getCmp('myToggle').setValue(true); // enable
Ext.getCmp('myToggle').setValue(false); // disable
```